# Decimal representation in python

Tags: python, math, floating-point, precision, euclidean-distance

When given input Iam getting result like 1.0 but I need it to be 1.000000000000
How should I modify within hypot??

```
small=1000000000
from math import hypot
def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = iter(iterable), iter(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
n=int(input())
l1=[]
l2=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    c,d=list(map(int,input().split()))
    l1.append(c)
    l2.append(d)
a=tuple(l1)
b=tuple(l2)
dist = [float(hypot(p2[0]-p1[0], p2[1]-p1[1])) for p1, p2 in pairwise(tuple(zip(a, b)))]
for x in dist:
    if x<small:
        small=x
print(small)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `format` method like so:

```
format(math.pi, '.12g') # Give 12 significant digits of pi

format(math.pi, '.2f') # Give 2 digits of pi after decimal point
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your print to

```
print(f'{small:.12f}')
```